# REACT NATIVE: How to get value of TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to get value of `TextInput` and `Picker` and insert it into my `Flatlist`. The ways that i did i can just insert value of `TextInput`, but without `Picker`,
or i did with `Picker` but couldnot get value of `TextInput`.
Here is my code:

These are UseState

```
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text style = {styles.item}> {item.name}</Text>)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}  
           />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the value of textInput while adding the data to flatlist.

```
<Button
  title="Save"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
  onPress={() => {
    // You forgot to add the value of textInput to the data
    if (selectedValue && text) setData([...data, { name: selectedValue, textInput: text }]);
    console.log("sec");
  }}
/>
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <React.Fragment>
    <Text style={styles.item}> {item.name}</Text>
    // Displaying the data of textInput
    <Text style={styles.item}>{item.textInput}</Text>
    </React.Fragment>}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: By the way how to make my Flatlist Scrollable, now it is not scrolling lol )

Comment: @Feliks_JS It is by default scrollable you just need to give it more components to scroll and limit its height you can try adding style={{flex:1}} to flatlist. If the problem still persisits start a new question and drop a link i would be happy to solve that query too :)